# Como retornar uma lista passando uma TVP como parâmetro

Tags: lista, procedure, stored-procedures

Boa tarde pessoal.
Estou escrevendo um método de consulta e preciso passar uma lista de cargos para a minha procedure para obter uma lista de funcionários. Estou tentando usar uma TVP ao invés de enviar uma string com Ids concatenados. Porém, não sei como adicionar o parâmetro.

Segue o código atual (não está funcionando dessa forma):

```
public IList<Funcionarios> Selecionar(DataTable TVPcargo)
    {
        IList<Funcinarios> resultado;
        TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
        options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))
        {
            using (Database database = new Database("stringDB"))
            {
                DbCommand cmd = database.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "ProcRetornaFunc";

                database.AddInParameter(cmd, "@Cargo", SqlDbType.Structured, TVPcargo);

                resultado = new List<Funcionarios>(database.MapRows<Funcionarios>(cmd, MapearRegistro));
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Um detalhes que esqueci de mencionar é que a procedure retorna os valores corretamente quando chamada diretamente no SQL Server. O problema é que não estou sabendo como adicionar o parametro tvp e retornar a lista.